# Overloading functions like Mean for distributions

Tags: distributions, upvalues

I'd like to understand how functions like Mean are overloaded to provide the right behavior for the distributions in Mathematica (like NormalDistribution or PoissonDistribution).

I originally assumed it was through the use of UpValues, but now I'm not so sure...

So, if I wanted to implement a function or distribution and define a behavior for it when another function like Mean is applied to it, how would I go about it?  I know it's *not* the following:

```
f[x_]:=2+x
f /: Mean[f[x_]] := 3 x
```

Desired behavior:

```
f[3]
Mean[f[3]]

(*
==> 5
==> 9
*)
```

Comment: Have you seen [`ProbabilityDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html)?

Comment: Nope - also really useful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Symbolic(!) distributions are recognized by their head, not by their `PDF`:

```
Mean[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]]
```

> Mean[E^(-(x^2/2))/Sqrt[2 π]]

So instead of messing around with `Mean`, I would rather suggest

```
distro /: PDF[distro[μ_, σ_], x_] := E^(-((x - μ)^2/(2 σ^2)))/(Sqrt[2 π] σ);
distro /: Mean[distro[μ_, σ_]] := μ;
distro /: Variance[distro[μ_, σ_]] := σ^2
Mean[distro[0, 1]]
Variance[distro[0, 1]]
```

> 0
>
> 1

Answer (score 6):

This works:

```
Unprotect[Mean];
SetAttributes[Mean, HoldFirst];
Protect[Mean];
f[x_] := 2 + x
f /: Mean[f[x_]] := 3 x
```

Since using `Unprotect` is not reccomended here's another way.

```
mean[x_] := Mean[x]
SetAttributes[mean, HoldFirst]
f[x_] := 2 + x
f /: mean[f[x_]] := 3 x
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that `SetAttributes[Mean, HoldFirst]` is likely to break many internal functions that depend on `Mean`

Comment: Thanks for this solution - I did learn something from your answer but I was trying to avoid setting DownValues.